# Calling Python 3 script from AppleScript

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, automator, python

I have a Python 3 script that I'd like to add as a Service using Automator. The idea is that I can right click on a text file, and an option will display to run my script on said file.

The shebang for my Python script is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

This script works fine and as expected in Terminal. However, when I attempt to automate this with AppleScript/Automator like so:

```
on run {input, parameters}

tell application "Terminal"
    do shell script "/path/to/script.py $@"
end tell

return input
end run
```

I run into issues, namely:

```
Terminal got an error: env: python3: No such file or directory
```

I've read [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2065/_index.html), among other places, that AppleScript by design only allows access to Unix commands, and will not for example source your bash profile (thus we do not have access to our $PATH by default). However I was under the impression that providing explicit paths was a workaround.

I've tried changing the `do shell` to this:

```
do shell script "/usr/bin/python3 /path/to/script.py $@"
```

and I've tried changing the shebang to this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env /usr/bin/python3
```

But nothing seems to work. Is it simply just not possible to execute a Python 3 script via AppleScript? I've not been able to find a viable workaround in my searches.

**Edit:** Additional info:

```
$ type -a python3
python3 is /usr/local/bin/python3
```

Comment: Start the Terminal application and type the following into your shell : `type -a python3` then edit your post with the command and the results.

Comment: Done. Since it looks like that's a different path, I wonder if I can symlink `/usr/bin/python3` to `/usr/local/bin/python3` or vice versa to avoid this issue across the environment.

Comment: Why do you expect do shell script "/usr/bin/python3 /path/to/script.py $@" to work? Your python3 is in /usr/local/bin What happens if you use the correct path?

Comment: Touche. I got confused, the path on my Linux server is `/usr/bin/python3` so I used that without checking.

Answer (score 2):

Solved my problem by changing the `do shell` to:

```
do shell script "/usr/local/bin/python3 /path/to/script.py $@"
```

and letting the shebang stay as:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Comment: Thanks for your question. I had to point to the shims `do shell script "/Users/FFish/.pyenv/shims/python ~/myscript.py"`for my pyenv install